# Let $m\in\Bbb N$. If $m$ is not prime, prove $\{1,2,...,m-1\}$ does not form a group under modulo-$m$ multiplication.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, modular-arithmetic

Let $m$ be a positive integer. If $m$ is not prime, prove that the set $\{1,2,...,m-1\}$ does not form a group under modulo-$m$ multiplication.

I know I can use the axioms of a group to prove this. But I am unable to think how I should approach this?

If I show this is not a group for, let us say $m=6$, will it suffice to prove this is not a group? Also, I may have to show this is true for all non-primes and not just a single example.

I am looking for general proof for such questions.

Comment: Do you have any ideas yourself?

Comment: I know I have to use only the definition of a field, i.e. the axioms.

Comment: Think about the implications of $m$ being not prime

Comment: Not the axioms of a field but the axioms of a group. To show that something *is* a group you need to show that all axioms hold. How do you show that something *is not* a group?

Comment: I have an answer lined up. If you add some context to your question (with an [edit]), I'll post it.

Comment: An example: Take $m=6.$ What is $2 \times 3$ in this structure? Is the structure closed under multiplication?

Comment: Will it be enough for the proof? I mean to prove this is not a group.

Comment: No. It would be just one example. You need something more substantial to show your result holds for all such $m$.

Comment: If you look at the definition of "not prime", perhaps you can generalize the $2 \times 3$ example to become a general proof.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not closed. Since $m$ is not prime, by definition, there exist $a,b\in\{2,\dots, m-1\}$ such that $m=ab$. But $m\pmod{m}\notin\{1,\dots, m-1\}$.

Comment: Can you elaborate, please?

Comment: Sure. What's the first thing about my answer that's causing you trouble, @AtifAli?

Comment: I do not understand how it holds for all nonprime numbers. Also, you have not shown anywhere that remainder will be zero and it will not be closed.

Comment: Well, by definition, $m$ is the product of elements in $\{2,\dots, m-1\}$. What would happen, then, @AtifAli, if the set *is* closed under multiplication?

Comment: I understand now, As $m$ is the product of any two elements $a,b\in \{2,...,m-1\}$,  so under module-$m$, it will be $0$. Hence not closed.

Comment: Yes, that's right, @AtifAli. If you're satisfied with my answer, please don't forget to accept it by clicking the check mark.

Comment: How will we show this in the proof that it is 0 under module-$m$?

Comment: Note that $m\notin \{1,\dots, m-1\}$, @AtifAli.

Comment: Also, it's "modulo $m$", not "module-$m$", @AtifAli.

Comment: Please elaborate *in your answer*, and not in discussions below the answer, with an additional 5 comments explaining what was an incomplete answer to start.

Comment: But the answer is complete, @amWhy. What could I possibly add?

Comment: I get it.  But it is clear the OP wasn't ready for it.  All is good.  Thanks for checking.  I just like to see edits to answers to summarize/include further information revealed.  It's totally okay to elaborate in comments; I simply think it would help improve Q&A if such summaries were made.  But admittedly, that's just my personal preference.

Comment: I don't find the statement $m \not\in \{ 1,2, \ldots,m-1\}$ completely adequate for an elementary proof (and I would probably take a mark off if grading an exam with this as solution). It looks as though you could prove in the same way that $\{1,2\}$ under multiplication mod $3$ is not a group, because $2 \times 2 = 4 \not\in\{1,2\}$.  It should say something like $m \bmod m \not\in \{ 1,2, \ldots,m-1\}$.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback, @DerekHolt; I have edited my answer accordingly.